Can Windows even work, if the System32 folder is missing?
On July 19 of this year, the CrowdStrike debacle occurred. It hit many of our servers at work and several desktop PCs as well. I think it hit my desktop PC at work, because I remember reading about where CrowdStrike put those corrupted .sys files, which were buried within the System32 folder on my Windows 11 Enterprise desktop.
However, I was also under a lot of pressure to get some projects done and at the time the impact wasn't severe on my desktop. However, in the last couple of weeks I've noticed my desktop not behaving very well. Often any application I'm in, like Chrome, MS Edge, MS Word, MS Excel, Visual Studio, etc., will suddenly close. And the BSOD are beginning to occur more frequently. It used to be once a month, now it's every other week.
So, a couple of days ago I looked up those articles again, so I can get rid of the corrupted .sys files placed in that CrowdStrike under System32. Only now, for some mysterious reason, I can no longer find the System32 folder on my C:\ drive! That doesn't make sense to me. Wouldn't it be the case that if the System32 folder and everything within it, were to have been deleted (not by me, BTW), then my workstation PC would not even start, when I rebooted it? I've rebooted it within the last week, and it comes up. So, I'm thinking it is still there, just hidden from me, for some reason. If I'm correct, then how do I get into that CrowdStrike folder under System32, when I cannot even see the System32 folder using File Explorer, or PowerShell, etc.?

no, windows cannot function without c:\windows\system32. see here for some details about why, and what might happen if you did. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-system32/ . if you go to Explorer.exe > Options > View (tab) > Hide protected operating system files is it checked? how about hidden files?

"So I can get rid of the corrupted .sys files placed in that CrowdStrike" - If the corrupt system file was on your system, your system would not boot into Windows, and CrowdStrike would not be operational.  Are either of those things true? Windows cannot boot without System32, by default, the folder is hidden.  The stability problems seems unrelated to CloudStrike system files by the way.

@FrankThomas you are right, the System32 folder is under the Windows folder. My mistake, I am VERY sorry for having brought about this confusion. Anyway, I see the CrowdStrike folder under the Windows\System32\drivers folder.

Glad you found it!

Honestly, though, if you have even a whiff of crowdstrike on your drive, consider purchasing a new drive and starting over.

@Yorik, CrowdStrike is not the kind of software you run outside of an enterprise, so even with a new disk, the enterprise policies will just put it back.

The System32 directory is vital for the operating system functionality. However, the issue here is that System32 is actually located in C:\Windows directory, not on the root of the C:\ drive. System32 is stored directly in the Windows directory on the root of the C:\ drive, however, you were looking at C:\, which is not the location of the System32 directory.

Often any application I'm in, like Chrome, MS Edge, MS Word, MS Excel, Visual Studio, etc., will suddenly close. And the BSOD are beginning to occur more frequently. It used to be once a month, now it's every other week.

This is likely just the system instability - perhaps unstable drivers, Windows updates, and malware are the most likely reasons. Without the System32 directory, there would be no chance for the operating system to boot. I might recommend to reinstall Windows - it's probably the best action to take.
